# File does not exist in S3 using Laravel even though it is there

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3, upload

I am building a website and I'm uploading some image files to S3 and then I am trying to delete the same files but for some reason Laravel doesn't find the file even though I've triple checked that the file is there in S3.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logic;

use App\UrlRequest;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class OldRequests {

    /**
     * Gets all requests older than 1 day and deletes the corresponding image
     * in s3 if it has not been already deleted
     */
    static function ifOlderThan1DaysDeleteImage()
    {
        $now = time();
        $time1DaysAgo = $now - (1*24*60*60);
        $datetime1DaysAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time1DaysAgo);

        $notDeletedYet = UrlRequest::where('image_deleted', '=', 0)
            ->where('created_at', '<', $datetime1DaysAgo)
            ->get();

        foreach ($notDeletedYet as $request)
        {
            if ( ! Storage::disk('s3')->exists('screenshots/153228343051117.png'))
            {
                throw new Exception('Image file not found in S3.');
            }

            $result = Storage::disk('s3')->delete('screenshots/153228343051117.png');

            if ($result);
            {
                $request->image_deleted = 1;
                $request->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code throws the exception: Image file not found in S3.

Note that the file name is hard-coded in though usually it comes from the $request variable which is an instance of the UrlRequest model.

I have no idea how to proceed with this so any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I've tried the above code again and it worked once; however I uploaded a new image and now it doesn't work again.

EDIT2: It currently works, it started working by itself...

Comment: Have you checked that your s3 instance has a folder called screenshots. Have you checked that your laravel actually connected the the same bucket?

Comment: @Marcus yes the bucket has a folder screenshots and Laravel connect successfully because I upload the image from the same project.

Comment: What does ´Storage::disk('s3')->getVisibility('screenshots/153228343051117.png');´ give you? Does the ARN give you permission to delete files on your bucket? How did you upload the file?

Comment: @DimitriMostrey it currently works, it started working by itself...

Comment: Good to hear. Starting with S3 was a steep learning curve for me. It took me a week to get it right. Now serving a million files without a glitch. Was it a IAM/ARN setting? Whatever. It works.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I don't know what was the issue I didn't change the code it just started working as it should cuz the code is correct, I guess it could've been an S3 issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the loop runs more than once it will throw that error in your test because the  file is hardcoded.

$notDeletedYet probably returns more then one object so when you run that method with the hard coded string the first iteration will remove the file as intended and the second iteration will not find the file which will result in your exception

Comment: There is currently only one file and I check in the database and then in S3 whether  it was marked off as deleted and the file deleted from S3 respectively and neither is done.

Comment: So if you dd($notDeletedYet) it returns just one?

Comment: Yes, it's just one - also, I just tried it again and it started working... hopefully it will continue to work.

Comment: I it might have been a problem with S3

Comment: Okey hope you figure out what was causing it